# Know which program creates a file at startup

Tags: linux, startup, monitor, boot, tmp

I'd like to know which process creates a file at startup in Linux, for example in /tmp.
Every time I boot Ubuntu I find a file in /tmp even though I delete it each time.
I haven't found out how to monitor it at startup with commands like lsof.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Which file exactly under `/tmp`, which Linux distribution?

Comment: It looks like a hash file (ssh-3dyCWi8IYqNf) that probably has to do with ssh client but anyway I'm interested in knowing it for any file...

Comment: Perhaps `ssh-agent`....